# How I get the selected Index from select list and send it to a database table?

Tags: jsp, scriptlet

In JSP, I want to get the selected Index Number of an item from a select list and send it to a database table on clicking a button.

Please dont use javascript but however you can use java scriplet(recommended). Tell 
me if there are any other ways.

Just give me an small example and I will be happy.

Comment: A very typical implementation is concatenate the index of the list in some form field with some sort of separator like `|` . 
`<input type="checkbox" value="<%=i%>|<%=othervalue%>" name="selected_field"/>`
You can access the value from servlet by 
`String[] selected = request.getParameterValues("selected_field");`

Comment: What if i have different Select option names..

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by option names

Comment: I meant to say that  `String[] selected = request.getParameterValues("selected_field");` would show the selected text not the selected ID. I want the selected ID.

Comment: No, `request.getParameterValues("selected_field");` will give you the `value` attribute of your `<input>` tag. As shown in previous snippet, your id is concatenated in `value` attribute. `selected[0].split("\\|")[0]` will be your id. And by the way the `request.getParameterValues()` is meant for checkbox, you can do the same for `<select>` with `request.getParameter()`

Comment: `selected[0].split("\\|")[0]` I needed this . But can you tell me the code. Suppose I want to store this ID in string str. Then???

Comment: I think you better edit your question on what exactly you need to achieve. Your question is way too abstract. Some code snippets on what you have tried so far would help too.

Comment: I got it.. My problem is solved